# Removing connected contours from alphabet

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

There is a project, I am working upon, so the original image is this after applying k-means clustering with 4 clusters:
k means image
[image]
I wanted to extract the F present in the image, I used color based filtering with cv2.inrange(), this resulted in:
color filtered image
[image]
how can I separate the F without any connected components that it is having ?.

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV morphological operations like Erosion, Dilation, Opening, Closing to isolate the 'F'?

Comment: yes that works a bit but results are not an entirely clear  "F".